# Connecting my project to Google+ is pending forever

Tags: google-api, google-plus

In Google API's [dashboard](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) there is an option to Request connection to Google+ Page.
I've requested to connect to a product page I've created in Google+, but it's been in "pending" state to this page ever since (weeks).
I didn't fin'd any clue what is wrong or what I should do. 
Any advice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This process is something that Google doesn't have to approve but you yourself have to make sure to confirm on both the API Console **and** on your Google+ Page.

Make sure to go through all the steps mentioned here:
https://developers.google.com/+/features/analytics#setup-insights